# Changing the output resolution (hdmi) on Android 9

Tags: android, linux, resolution, hdmi

I would like to change the output resolution (hdmi) programmatically.
I understand that we can change the hdmi resolution by changing the value of the file /sys/class/display/mode.
When connecting to the device with adb shell, I have access to file /sys/class/display/mode. But only the system user can write into it :
-rw-r--r-- 1 system system   4096 2023-01-02 14:53 mode

When I try to write to the file /sys/class/display/mode I have no permission because I need to be system user
command use : [echo 2160p60hz > /sys/class/display/mode]

How can I change the value of the file /sys/class/display/mode ?

ps.

With command [wm size] in the shell I can change the resolution of the screen, but not the resolution of the hdmi

Comment: Hi, I want to do the same as you. I also tryed "wm size". Did you found a solution? Thanks!!

Comment: do you have root access to the device?

Comment: It seem to be a hardware problème.  The problem Can bé solve with "wm size". Also i have Access to root